# Size of webpage is two times bigger in height than expected

Tags: html, css

I can't tell if it's a problem with my divs or HTML but my page is two times bigger in height than expected (my current theory is that it's loading where the text would've been if it wasn't in a div). Is there a way to force set the webpage to a certain size in CSS or HTML? Thanks.

HTML div:

```
<div class="Divname">
    <center><h3>Text</h3></center>
    <center><h4>Text
    </h4></center>
    <center><h4>Text</h4></center>
    <center><h4>Text</h4></center>
    <center><h4>Text</h4></center>
</div>
```

CSS div:

```
.divname {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  top: 50%;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 223px;;
    right: 230px;
}
```

Comment: Hello. Could you please share the code so we can help you better

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can use `max-height` rule.

Fixed value:

```
.my-container {
  max-height: 50px;
}
```

Or view height percentage:

```
max-height: 50vh;
```

More details here:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-height.asp

But it could be helpful if you share your code...